# Problem on the_excerpt(); function <the_excerpt> <the_content>

Tags: the-content, excerpt

I am working on wordpress but I have problem when I write
the_content('read more');

then on indexpage each post load full data of post but I want to

but when I am using the_excerpt();
then wordpress return a 10-15 word on index page and when i click for read more or click on title of post then 30-40 words just show without images...

Please help me what should I do?

check here is [screenshot](http://imageupload.org/getfile.php?id=180900&a=269cf2b1bb8ff525853c426226f2d9e7&t=4f3a5bb5&o=1681F90D1D99ECA49AA7B7F9F214BAAE604CEDE1E4EF3FFEA48827172C44A4FD6C0B9DE40D01&n=problem.jpg&i=1)

Comment: Are you saying that you want the post excerpt to appear on the blog posts index, and that you want the full post content to appear on single blog posts?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you want the full post content to appear only on single blog posts, and that you want the post excerpt to appear everywhere else, try something like this inside your Loop in `index.php`:

```
<?php
if ( is_singular() ) {
    the_content( 'Read More' );
} else {
    the_excerpt();
}
?>
```

Additional Codex reading:

- [`the_content()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content)
- [`the_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt)
- [`is_singular()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular)
- [query conditionals](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)